# Git: Pushing multiple branches using wildcards

Tags: git

Here are my list of branches:

```
$ git br
  BR_4_1_4
* BR_4_2_0
  BR_4_2_0_phase2
  feature/subchecks
  master
  wip/central-build-dir
  wip/cmake
  wip/gcc-pedantic
  wip/noncopyable-cserializable
```

I'd like to push all of the branches starting with `wip/`. So I tried this:

```
$ git push -u origin wip/*
Everything up-to-date
```

But it says everything is up to date? This can't be since I know a few of these branches do not exist on the remote. Should this work? If not, what's the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try

```
git push -u origin refs/heads/wip/*
```

Comment: Didn't know about pushing local refs, +1.

Comment: How is this different from specifying `wip/*`? Shouldn't Git search inside 'refs/heads' by default? I don't have to type in the full path for normal branches without wildcards.